# Is it possible to load a XSL stylesheet from a remote server in ASP classic

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic

I do not have disk access on the server so I need to load a XSL stylesheet from a remote location.

Instead of this...

```
set xsl = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xsl.async = false
xsl.load(Server.MapPath("xsl.xsl"))
```

Is something like this possible to load a XSL stylesheet?

```
xsl.Open "get", "http://www.example.com/xsl.xsl" , False
xsl.Send
```

If above is not possible can the stylesheet be put internally in the ASP file. If so, how is that accomplished?

UPDATE - Full code

```
Dim xml, xsl, url, url2

url = "https://www.example.xml"
url2 = "http://www.example.com/xsl/xsl.xsl"
Set xml =  Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "get", url, False
xml.Send
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"

set xsl = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xsl.async = false

xsl.load(Server.MapPath("xsl.xsl"))

'xsl.Open "get", url2, False
'xsl.Send

Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
Response.Write xml.responseXML.transformNode(xsl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim req, sheet
Set req = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
req.open "GET", "http://example.com/sheet.xsl", False
req.send
If req.status = 200 Then
  Set sheet = req.responseXML
  ...
Else
  '  handle HTTP problems here
End If
```

Comment: getting a server error of <font face="Arial" size=2>
<p>msxml3.dll</font> <font face="Arial" size=2>error '80070057'</font>
<p>
<font face="Arial" size=2>The parameter is incorrect.
</font>
<p>
<font face="Arial" size=2>/xsl/xsl.asp</font><font face="Arial" size=2>, line 35</font> "

Comment: Can you tell us which line of code caused that error? And I used the program id `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` which would lead to an `msxml6.dll` error and not `msxml3.dll` error you have shown, so you have more and/or different code than the one I posted.

Comment: Response.Write xml.responseXML.transformNode(sheet)

Comment: Have you used MSXML 6.0 consistently for loading both `xml` as well as `sheet` document variables? Otherwise it is not going to work as you can't mix different MSXML versions. So make sure all program ids you use end with `.6.0`, like `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` or `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0`.

Comment: If I use Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") to load the XML I get this...This Virtual Directory does not allow objects to be executed.

Comment: OK, I tested your solution on a different server and it does work however on the server that I need to use it on only Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") will work.