# Take transformed XML and then parse data from certain nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, asp-classic

I have an XML file which is transformed via a XSL file into XML format which in turn I would like to loop through a certain node to extract its text. I am having trouble parsing out specific text from after the transformation..

```
 tfmSheet = xml.responseXML.transformNode(sheet)
```

The code works fine until the For/Next loop. I get the feeling that I am missing a step or two after the above line but not sure what.

```
<--- previous code omitted for clarity ---> 

Set xsl = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xsl.open "GET", "http://www.example.com/xsl.xsl", False
xsl.send
If xsl.status = 200 Then
Set sheet = xsl.responseXML
End If

tfmSheet = xml.responseXML.transformNode(sheet)

- Am I missing something here? -

tfmList = tfmSheet.SelectNodes("//xmldata/Orders")

For Each tfmOrder In tfmList
    Set OrderDate = tfmOrder.SelectSingleNode("OrderDate")
    If Not OrderDate Is Nothing Then
    OrderDateText = OrderDate.text
    End If

Response.write OrderDateText

Next

Response.write tfmSheet
```

Continuation of this question...

[Is it possible to load a XSL stylesheet from a remote server in ASP classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954843/is-it-possible-to-load-a-xsl-stylesheet-from-a-remote-server-in-asp-classic)

UPDATED transformed XML shown below

```
<xmldata>
    <Orders>
        <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
        <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
        <OrderDate>6/13/2013 5:08:00 PM</OrderDate>
        <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
        <PONum></PONum>
        <ShippingMethodID>502</ShippingMethodID>
        <OrderDetails>
            <OrderDetailID>25676</OrderDetailID>
            <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
            <ProductCode>58309-SYL</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
            <ProductName>ABCD</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
            <Quantity>300</Quantity>
            <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
        <OrderDetails>
            <OrderDetailID>25677</OrderDetailID>
            <OrderID>87709</OrderID>
            <ProductCode>ABCDEFG</ProductCode>
            <ProductID>9757</ProductID>
            <ProductName>XYZ 2</ProductName>
            <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
            <Quantity>300</Quantity>
            <TotalPrice>1425.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
        <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
        <CustomerID>123456</CustomerID>
        <OrderDate>10/30/2012 3:02:00 PM</OrderDate>
        <PaymentMethodID>5</PaymentMethodID>
        <PONum></PONum>
        <ShippingMethodID>141</ShippingMethodID>
        <OrderDetails>
        <OrderDetailID>21472</OrderDetailID>
        <OrderID>84757</OrderID>
        <ProductCode>58309</ProductCode>
        <ProductID>9756</ProductID>
        <ProductName>XYZ 12V</ProductName>
        <ProductPrice>4.7500</ProductPrice>
        <Quantity>160</Quantity>
        <TotalPrice>760.0000</TotalPrice>
        </OrderDetails>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
         next Order...
    </Orders>
<xmldata>
```

Comment: Don't know what kind of XML you get in the response, but maybe you need to define the namespaces from the response file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transformNode` returns a string, not a DOM document. So change

```
tfmSheet = xml.responseXML.transformNode(sheet)

tfmList = tfmSheet.SelectNodes("//xmldata/Orders")
```

to

```
Set tfmSheet = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xml.responseXML.transformNodeToObject sheet, tfmSheet
tfmList = tfmSheet.SelectNodes("//xmldata/Orders")
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I am getting this error...  Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'tfmList'

Comment: Fixed, added Set... Set tfmList = tfmSheet.SelectNodes("//xmldata/Orders")